# Normal buildtime for "nix-build -A plutus-playground.server"

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

How long should the following build normaly take, when the correct "IOHK binary cache" is set at "nix.conf"?

`nix-build -A plutus-playground.server`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me it took roughly 2-4 hours on virtual box but it really depends on what environment your setting it up in. For example a virtual box will take much longer than a computer running on Linux or a wsl instance.
Overall expect to wait 30 min - 4h.

Comment: I had luck and on my WSL2 "Ubuntu 20.04" Machine the build finished after approximately 30 Minutes.
→ The first "nix-shell" calls also take some times, but therefore the recalls finishes quick.

Answer (score 3):

For me it's as follows:

`nix-build -A plutus-playground.server` -> 262s

`nix-build -A plutus-playground.client` -> 25s

`nix-shell`                             -> 1715s

This is after properly setting all the IOHK caches correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].